# Show text for specific customer group in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to show the text in the basket for customer in groups with the ID number 4, 6, 7,
8,

In cart-summary.tpl file I write
`{if $logged}{if $customer.id_default_group|in_array:[4, 6, 7, 8]}Test{/if}{/if}`

but I get errors, anyone can help me?

Comment: Please use only relevant tags. This question has nothing to do with .NET's Task Parallel Library or any kind of parallelism

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{if $customer.is_logged}{if $customer.id_default_group|in_array:[4, 6, 7, 8]}Test{/if}{/if}
```

or

```
{if $customer.is_logged and $customer.id_default_group|in_array:[4, 6, 7, 8]}Test{/if}
```

Comment: The codes are not working. I checked what IDs they show and it always comes out 0. Perhaps because I use knowband's supercheckout. I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you ask without touching the core and the theme by writing a small module that hooks into one of the cart's display hooks (check out the ones called *displayCart**)

It's not good practice to modify TPLs directly for this purpose.

Inside the hook you can get the logged customer id from the Context :

```
$idCustomer = (int)$this->context->customer->id;
if ($idCustomer < 1 ) {
     return;
}
$objCustomer = new Customer($idCustomer);
$idDefaultGroup = (int)$objCustomer->id_default_group;
```

Then you can insert your check :

```
$isCustomerInMyGroup = in_array($idDefaultGroup, [4,6,7,8]);
```

and send this value to a custom smarty template to displaying the information :

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('is_customer_in_my_group' => 
    $isCustomerInMyGroup);
return $this->context->smarty->fetch(
                module:mymodule/views/templates/hook/hook.tpl)'
```

Then in "hook.tpl" you can insert your HTML content

```
{if $logged && $is_customer_in_my_group}
... MY CONTENT HERE ...
{/if}
```

See here on how to getting started in modules development :

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/